# AngularJS 1.3 ui router go back to history page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use this **routes** controller in order to navigate to page A. At page A it is possible to navigate to page B.

```
function getRecordReportState() {
        var state = {
            name: 'auth.recordreport',
            url: '/recordreport/:userId/:month/:year',
            templateUrl: 'app/recordReport/recordReport/recordReport.html',
```

In page B I use this command to navigate back to page A:

```
function cancelAndGoBack() {
    $window.history.back();
}
```

My question now would be if there is a possibility to navigate to page A programmatically where I also can set the parameter /:userId/:month/:year ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can simply do:

$state.go('auth.recordreport', {userId: 'someuser', month: 4, year: 2016});